# Comparing x and x=f(x) in c

Tags: c

In C, how can I compare a variable to the result of a function, which I then want to store within the variable for later use? With the code shown below, it always returns true where f is a function that just returns x-1.

Something like this:

```
if (x == (x = f(x))) ...
```

Comment: I think you probably need a temporary variable to hold the old value.

Comment: `if (x == f(x)) { /* no need to assign */ ... } else { x = f(x); }` and assume the compiler will optimize it.

Comment: @pmg The compiler won't optimize it if `f(x)` is not in the same TU or not pure.

Answer (score 1):

```c
Type old_x = x;
x = f(x);
if ( x == old_x ) {
  ...
}
```

or

```c
Type new_x = f(x);
if ( new_x == x ) {
  ...
} else {
   x = new_x;
}
```